# Debug 504 error Docker container

Tags: http-status-code-504

we have a docker container which serves as Data Access Layer (Swagger API). The base image is Java. It's written in scala and the dockerfile is build by a sbt build. This container is between a frontend and a database (neo4j).

But now we often get a 504 error (gateway timeout) whe we try to access our DAL container. We're able to scale it down and up and than it works again for 5/10 minutes.

What's the best way to debug a 504 error in a Java Docker container. I would think its no problem with the Kubernetes service above (this is always working for a lot of other containers). Also neo4j is still running. So we need to know if it's a problem with the container or with the code.